# Laravel PHP Update HTML Table view with Drop downs

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, httprequest

I have read a lot into this and I am trying to find a way to refresh an HTML table in my view.

I want to use some drop down menus to select variables that are then inserted into my queries.

In my controller I have queries that populate the drop downs, and a query that is populating the table and paginating it, but I need to find out how to make the list of entries in the table change when the drop down is changed.

I have read into this quite a bit and a lot of people use javascript with onchange, but I am having trouble figuring out how to make that work with more than one drop down changing, and if possible was interested in changing the view without changing the url, but if not need some pointers or guidance on how to keep track of the variables in the url when there is more than one filter.

Edit:

View:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Vulnerabilities')

@section('sidebar')
  @parent
@endsection

@section('content')
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="form-group"{{ $errors->has('vulns') ? ' has-error' : '' }}>
        <label for="vulnerability" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Vulnerability</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="cve_id" id="cve_id" onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;">
          <option value="" selected>{{ $vuln }}</option>
          @foreach ($vulns as $vn)
            <option value="{{ $vn->cve }}">{{ $vn->cve }}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
        @if ($errors->has('vulns'))
          <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('vulns') }}</strong>
          </span>
          @endif
      </div>
      Vulnerable Hosts:<br/>
      @foreach ($vhost as $object)
        {{ $object->host }}<br/>
      @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      Description:<br/>
      @foreach ($desc as $object)
        <p>{{ $object->description }}</p>
        <br/>
      @endforeach
      Solution:<br/>
      @foreach ($sltn as $object)
      <p>{{ $object->solution }}</p>
      <br/>
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
@endsection
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Item;

class VulnerabilityController extends Controller {
  /**
     * Return View file
     *
     * @var array
     */
  public function Vulnerability() {
    return redirect('vulnerability/CVE');
  }

  public function listHosts(Request $request) {

    $vuln = $request->vuln;   

    $vhost = DB::table('items')
              ->select('host')
              ->where('cve', 'like', $vuln)
              ->groupBY('host')
              ->get();

    $vulns = DB::table('items')
             ->select('cve')
             ->groupBY('cve')
             ->get();

    $desc = DB::table('items')
            ->select('description')
            ->where('cve', 'like', $vuln)
            ->groupBy('description')
            ->get();

    $sltn = DB::table('items')
            ->select('solution')
            ->where('cve', 'like', $vuln)
            ->groupBy('solution')
            ->get();

    return view('vulnerability', compact('vhost', 'vulns', 'vuln', 'desc', 'sltn'));
  }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('vulnerability', 'VulnerabilityController@vulnerability');
Route::get('vulnerability/{vuln}', 'VulnerabilityController@listHosts');
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: That is what I have so far and it seems to work ok. Atm I am trying to find a way to put data into a table and then have multiple drop downs that can filter it. Would also like to know if there is a better or easier way to do what I have done here.

Comment: Also trying to figure out why, my route for /vulnerabilities didn't work by itself. I had to add a redirect in my main function in the controller that tells it to redirect to /vulnerability/cve, otherwise after selecting an item in drop down it would return me to /CVE_id, instead of /vulnerability/cve_id

Comment: Also worth noting, the above is not what I have so far on the table I am trying to do, it is a different page where I was testing out the idea with only one filter. That works pretty well, but I am trying to find if there is a way to more directly tie the filters and sorting to an HTML table, instead of reloading a different URL each time. So far my best idea has been to do basically the same thing as above, but add a submit button that when pressed parses the drop down selections into a custom uri, then pass it to my controller where it is parsed back into separate variables.

Comment: Turns out that laravel-datatables works pretty well for what I needed.